# Web.config authorization fall-through

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

I have in my web.config

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Admin/Page1">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SubAdmin"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Would this properly block everyone except "Administrator" and "SubAdmin" roles from Admin/Page1?

Or do I have to add `<allow roles="Administrator"/> <deny users="?"/>` to the Admin/Page1 section?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, keep web.configs in each folder instead of keeping in one web.config.

I'm not sure which role is more powerful - Administrator or SubAdmin. You need to keep the most powerful role inside the nested folder.

Inside Administrator only folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Inside SubAdmin and Administrator folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator, SubAdmin"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
<allow roles="Admin"/>
<allow roles="SubAdmin"/>
<deny users="*"/>
```

For future reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I have a lot of pages in the admin folder, all of which obviously the admin should be allowed to access along with whoever is specified for that individual page. I'm trying to avoid having a lot of repetitive lines.